# UIWebView scrolling issue

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview, scroll

I'm having trouble with a UIWebView on both the iPhone and the iPad.
The page that I'm loading is generated by the app which uses the javascript syntax highlighter library ( http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/ ) to syntax highlight the text that is loaded.

This works great, and it looks fine, however when I come to scrolling the webview I have problems. Horizontal scrolling is fine when you slide it, but when you let go it doesn't continue to scroll, so it seems like the inertial scrolling is not working?

Scrolling down on the other hand is completely different. When I can get it to scroll, the inertial part is working fine, but getting it to scroll is a bit harder. If you don't scroll down perfectly straight then it simply won't scroll down. If you do manage to get it straight, then you also seem to have to press and hold for half a second or so before you start scrolling, otherwise it simply won't scroll.

I'm getting really frustrated with it as I cannot find out what is going wrong!

Any help?

EDIT :

After more playing around, it seems that it is based on the HTML content, but I can't figure out what is causing it to mess up. If I load the content and don't run the syntax highlighter javascript function, then it loads fine, and scrolls without any problems and all is well. The moment I run the syntax highlighter I get the issues. The source that is produced by the syntax highlighter is here ( http://pastebin.com/c6Mnc9nb )
I know it looks horrible but it should be fine, and renders correctly. But as I say, that HTML causes the scrolling issues and I can't figure out why.

PLEASE can someone help! I really need this sorted so I can get my app published.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doesn't matter. Just replaced the syntax highlighting library instead.